# multiple substitutions on a string in bash

Tags: bash

I have a variable named `inet` which contains the following string:

```
inet="inetnum:        10.19.153.120 - 10.19.153.127"
```

I would like to convert this string to notation below:

```
10.19.153.120 10.19.153.127
```

I could easily achieve this with `sed 's/^inetnum: *//;s/^ -//'`, but I would prefer more compact/elegant solution and use bash. Nested parameter expansion does not work either:

```
$ echo ${${inet//inetnum: /}// - / }
bash: ${${inet//inetnum: /}// - / }: bad substitution
$
```

Any other suggestions? Or should I use `sed` this time?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can only do one substitution at a time, so you need to do it in two steps:

```
newinet=${inet/inetnum: /}
echo ${newinet/ - / }
```

Answer (score 11):

Use a regular expression in `bash` as well:

```
[[ $inet =~ ([0-9].*)\ -\ ([0-9].*)$ ]] && newinet=${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1:2}
```

The regular expression could probably be more robust, but should capture the two IP addresses in your example string. The two captures groups are found at index 1 and 2, respectively, of the array parameter `BASH_REMATCH` and assigned to the parameter `newinet`.